# Load web csv in github with c#

Tags: c#, .net, pandas, github, dataframe

estoy tratando de extraer y trabajar los datos de unos archivos en formato csv alojados en github (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MinCiencia/Datos-COVID19/master/output/producto1/Covid-19_std.csv). Primero pensé en usar la api de github, pero no encontré nada que me permitiera esto, acto seguido lo intenté utilizando HttpWebRequest y StreamReader, pero solo leyó la mitad del archivo y lanzó error por el largo. Tercer y último intento, utilicé DataFrame de Microsoft.Data.Analysis, pero el método LoadCsv parece solo realizar lectura de archivos locales.

Básicamente lo que busco es tratar los datos similar a como se hace con pandas para cuestiones de análisis, pero tengo como restricción utilizar lenguaje c# o c++ y limitar al mínimo el uso de APIs.

Nota. El uso sería para una aplicación de escritorio.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La dirección de donde quieres descargar el contenido es pública, por lo que solo necesitarás seleccionar un clase que sirva para este fin.

La plataforma .Net provee diferentes clases que puedes utilizar. En lo personal utilizo `HttpClient` contenida en el Namespace `System.Net.Http` y que puede ser utilizada tanto en .Net Core como en .Net Framework desde la versión 4.5

El siguiente ejemplo está en `C#`, para probarlo necesitas un formunario de Windows Form con un botón llamado `button1` y con el siguiente código en el evento click.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string csv = string.Empty;
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
    {
        csv = await http.GetStringAsync("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MinCiencia/Datos-COVID19/master/output/producto1/Covid-19_std.csv");
    }
            
    if(csv != string.Empty)
    {
        // Aquí puedes hacer uso del contenido del archivo
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que no se limita a Windows form, el bloque de instrucciones dentro del evento click también pueden ser utilizadas en cualquier otro tipo de proyecto (Consola, Wpf, Librería de Clases, etc.)

Comment: Considera leer [answer], editar y explicar tu aporte

Comment: @BetaM, gracias por la recomendación. Espero que ahora esté mejor mi respuesta.

Comment: Mucho mejor, tienes mi +1